# Adding quantity increment button in cart and mini cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, shopping-cart, mini-cart

I need to add a quantity increment button in cart page and mini cart popup like this.

[image]

I added the button but I can't assign the functionality. 
This is what I did 
 *app/code/Amsi/UserManagement/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock  name="checkout.cart.form">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override" as="renderer.list.custom"/>
            <arguments>
                <argument name="renderer_list_name" xsi:type="string">checkout.cart.item.renderers.override</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Amsi/UserManagement/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Amsi_UserManagement::cart/item/default.phtml" />

            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Amsi_UserManagement::cart/item/default.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

*app/code/Amsi/UserManagement/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml*

```
.......
<td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>">
    <div class="field qty">
        <label class="label" for="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control qty">
            <button>-</button>
            <input id="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
                   name="cart[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
                   data-cart-item-id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getSku() ?>"
                   value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getQty() ?>"
                   type="number"
                   size="4"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>"
                   class="input-text qty"
                   data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
                   data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
            <button >+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
......
```

How can i assign functionality to increment and decrements buttons ?

Comment: You jQuery to add functionality.

Comment: Where should i define my jquery function ?

Comment: Create a custom module for those increment & decrement field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

app/code/Amsi/UserManagement/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

I have added For both increment and decrementing quantity.

You can add the button near Quantiy using below code.

```
<div class="control qty">
   <input id="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
       name="cart[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
       data-cart-item-id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getSku() ?>"
       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getQty() ?>"
       type="number"
       size="4"
       title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>"
       class="input-text qty"
       data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
       data-role="cart-item-qty"/>                                                     

      /*Code to add increment and decrement button*/

   <div class="qty_control">
            <button type="button"  id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-upt" class="increaseQty"></button>
            <button type="button"   id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-dec"  class="decreaseQty"></button>
      </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
require(["jquery"],function($){
    $('#<?php echo $_item->getId();?>-upt, #<?php echo $_item->getId();?>-dec').on("click",function(){ 
        var $this = $(this);
        var ctrl = ($(this).attr('id').replace('-upt','')).replace('-dec','');          
        var currentQty = $("#cart-"+ctrl+"-qty").val();
        if($this.hasClass('increaseQty')){
            var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)+parseInt(1);
             $("#cart-"+ctrl+"-qty").val(newAdd);
        }else{
             if(currentQty>1){
                var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)-parseInt(1);
                $("#cart-"+ctrl+"-qty").val(newAdd); 
             }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is almost correct but it will work only when you are having 1 product in cart. Because increment and decrement in your code is managed by increment / decrement button's class i.e "increaseQty" & "decreaseQty". So if you want to make is available for n numbers of products in cart then you are required to replace this line in above code "$('.increaseQty, .decreaseQty').on("click",function(){"  with this line "$('#<?php echo $_item->getId();?>-upt, #<?php echo $_item->getId();?>-dec').on("click",function(){". Hence right now I have managed using ID so it will work perfect.

Comment: How does this trigger a change event so ko knows to show the 'update' button? I'm able to get the + - buttons working and changing the input value, but the 'update' button does not appear to actually save and update the cart

Comment: hi @aravind, above code works in cart page, not on minicart

Comment: Since minicart is rendered using KO.You need to override "module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html" file in vendor

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code.

If you don't have the files in below path, create a file with same name and copy & paste below code.

File Path: app\design\frontend\Sm\destino\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\item\default.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && option.option_type == 'file') -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && option.option_type != 'file') -->
                                <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                           
                    <span class="less">-</span>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty">                    
                    <span class="more">+</span>
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <!--<div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>-->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

File path: app\design\frontend\Sm\destino\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\minicart.phtml

If you don't have minicart.phtml file. copy from vendor folder and add below javascript.

Vendor file path: vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($){
        $('body').on("click",".more, .less",function(){
            var obj = $(this);
            var currentQty = obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').val();
            var iid = obj.siblings('.update-cart-item').attr('data-cart-item');

            if(obj.hasClass('more')){
                var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)+parseInt(1);
                obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').val(newAdd);
                obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').attr('data-item-qty',newAdd);
                //$('#update-cart-item-'+iid).click();
                $('.update-cart-item').show();
            } else {
                if(parseInt(currentQty) > 1){
                    var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)-parseInt(1);
                    obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').val(newAdd); 
                    obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').attr('data-item-qty',newAdd);
                    //$('#update-cart-item-'+iid).click();
                    $('.update-cart-item').show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you want my design, add below code in your less file.

```
.minicart-items{
    .item{
        .product{
            .product-item-details{
                .details-qty{
                    .more{
                        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                        height: 32px !important;
                        width: 20px;
                        text-align: center;
                        display: inline-block;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        line-height: 30px;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                    }

                    .less{
                        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                        height: 32px !important;
                        width: 20px;
                        text-align: center;
                        display: inline-block;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        line-height: 30px;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" data-validate="{'required-number':true,digits:true}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="qty-change">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="increaseQty">+</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="decreaseQty">-</a>
                </div>
            </div>

      <script>
require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/mage'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';

        $(".increaseQty").unbind('click').click(function () {
            if ($(this).parents('.field.qty').find("input.input-text.qty").is(':enabled')) {
                $(this).parents('.field.qty').find("input.input-text.qty").val((+$(this).parents('.field.qty').find("input.input-text.qty").val() + 1) || 0);
                $(this).parents('.field.qty').find("input.input-text.qty").trigger('change');
                $(this).focus();
            }
        });

        $(".decreaseQty").unbind('click').click(function () {
                if ($(this).parents('.field.qty').find("input.input- 
                        text.qty ").is(':enabled')){
                        $(this).parents('.field.qty').find("input.input- 
                            text.qty ").val(($(this).parents('.field.qty').find("
                            input.input -
                            text.qty ").val() - 1 > 0) 
                            ($(this).parents('.field.qty').find("input.input-text.qty").val() -
                                1): 0); $(this).parents('.field.qty').find("input.input-text.qty").trigger('change'); $(this).focus();
                    }
                });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can do it the super fast way just inject this jQuery snippet in your html head

jQuery('#shopping-cart-table :input[type="number"]').bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
jQuery(".update").click()
});