# Add Ajax Quantity Increment and Decrement Button on mini cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7, mini-cart

I  want to implement Ajax Quantity Increment and Decrement Button functionality on cart items on Minicart. I didn't find any article or any module to achieve this. as qty increment(+) and decrement(-) inside the mini cart product price and the total must change without clicking on update.Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216496/adding-quantity-increment-button-in-cart-and-mini-cart

Comment: Thanks for comments  Mukesh Prajapati but i need as qty increment(+) and decrement(-) inside the mini cart product price and the total must change without clicking on update.

Comment: yes, from above link you can add increment and increment functionality after that you have to write custom ajax code to update mini cart via ajax.

Comment: https://www.magearray.com/enhanced-mini-cart.html

This is available module for that

Comment: Thanks for comments Mukesh Prajapati the above link extension link doesn't contains demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make it easier by adding +1 and -1 links to change the quantity of each item. We will do this with some very simple JavaScript which takes the current value and adjusts it. Once this has been done, we submit the form through JavaScript to reduce customer effort.

```
<?php
  <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" id="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"/>
?>
```

> app/design/frontend/[interface_name]/[theme_name]/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

**Increase by one:**

```
<?php
  <a onclick="changeItemQuantity( <?php echo $_item->getId() ?>, 1 ); return false;" href="#"><img alt="add-arw" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/add-arw.png') ?>"></a>
?>
```

**Decrease by one:**

```
<?php
  <a onclick="changeItemQuantity( <?php echo $_item->getId() ?>, -1 ); return false;" href="#"><img alt="add-arw" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/add-arw.png') ?>"></a>
?>
```

Now the JavaScript function. We do not want it duplicated for every item so you can either put it in your theme’s JavaScript file or just below the table in the parent template -

> app/design/frontend/[interface_name]/[theme_name]/template/checkout/cart.phtml

```
function changeItemQuantity( id , num ) {
    var qty_id = "cart[" + id + "][qty]";
    var currentVal = parseInt( $(qty_id).value );
    if ( currentVal != NaN )
    {
        $(qty_id).value = currentVal + num;
        $("products-table-basket").submit();
    }
}
```

[image]

References

1. https://tomrobertshaw.net/2010/08/add-increase-and-decrease-quantity-buttons-to-items-in-magento-cart/
2. https://www.magearray.com/enhanced-mini-cart.html
3. https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Update-Cart-automatically-Using-Increment-and-decrement-Button/td-p/104958

Comment: Thanks for comment Aditya Shah but code does not works for me.

Comment: This is reference you need to enhance it

Comment: Aditya Shah can you please elaborate how can I get it

Comment: Okay,just a min

Comment: You can consult a way to ajax re-load block totals in cart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84767/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-trilok-kumar).

Comment: @AdityaShah, This applied in cart page but not in minicart

Answer (score 2):

You can download the extension and installed it for minicart Ajax Quantity Increment and Decrement Button.

https://github.com/kirtinariya1/MinicartAjaxQtyIncrementDecrement

Comment: Does this support 2.4.1 commerce edition? @Kirti Nariya

Comment: @zus It is working fine in 2.2 Please check in 2.4.1

Comment: FYI If click + (increment) or - (decrement )  first time not updating, if i click again then only it will reflect, how to solve this issue

Comment: Any help for ajax not working on first click. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/335615/57334